# How to understand the process of transforming research data into certain distribution (not statistical distribution)?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, frequency-distribution

Statistics is not my major and English is not my native language. **I tried to apply for data analysis or data science work in industry.** However, I do not know how to describe my research process below in a concise and professional way. I highly appreciated if you could provide me such help.

Background: I simulating properties of materials using different research packages, such as LAMMPS. The simulated data are only coordinates of atoms. Below are my data analysis.

step 1: clean the data to make sure the data complete and atom ID is unique and not exchangeable at different time moments (timesteps).

step 2: Calculated the neighbor atoms' distance of each center atom to find the target species (a configuration formed by several target atoms, such as Al-O-H, Si-O-H, Al-O-H2, H3-O)

step 3: count the amount of species as functions of space and/or time and draw the species distribution as functions of space and/or time, lifetime distribution of species.
NOTE: such distribution is different from statistical distribution, such as Normal Distribution, Binomial Distribution.

step 4: Based on above distribution, the correlation between species would be explored and interpreted.

After above steps, I study the mechanism behind based on materials selves and local environment.

Could anyone point out how to understand above steps in statistical terms or data analytic terms or others?

I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Good question, but it's off topic for SO. I've marked it to be moved to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RobertDodier, Thanks for your help.